# Find the minimum of $\frac{\sin x}{\cos y}+\frac {\cos x}{\sin y}+\frac{\sin y}{\cos x}+\frac{\cos y}{\sin x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, contest-math, maxima-minima

Let $0<x,y<\frac {\pi}{2}$ such that $\sin (x+y)=\frac 23$, then find the minimum of

$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos y}+\frac {\cos x}{\sin y}+\frac{\sin y}{\cos x}+\frac{\cos y}{\sin x}$$

A) $\frac 23$

B) $\frac 43$

C) $\frac 89$

D) $\frac {16}{9}$

E) $\frac{32}{27}$

---

My attempts:

I think that the all possible answers are wrong. Because, by Am-Gm inequality we have

$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos y}+\frac{\cos y}{\sin x}+\frac {\cos x}{\sin y}+\frac{\sin y}{\cos x}≥2+2=4.$$

But, Wolfram Alpha gives us a different result : The Global Minimum doesn't exist. However, ​the local minimum must be $6.$

But, still the problem is not solved. Because Wolfram's graph shows that the minimum can be less than $6$.

I also tried

Let $$\sin x=a,\cos y=b,\cos x=c,\sin y=d$$ with

$$ab+cd=\frac 23≥2\sqrt{abcd}\implies abcd≤\frac 19\\ a^2+c^2=b^2+d^2=1 $$

then I need

$$\min \left(\frac ab+\frac ba+\frac cd+\frac dc\right)$$

But, I can't do anything from here.  Finally, I attach the graph drawn by WA.

[image]

Comment: $$\frac{\sin x}{\cos y}+\frac{\cos y}{\sin x}+\frac {\cos x}{\sin y}+\frac{\sin y}{\cos x}+≥2+2=4$$

This is quite a nontrivial claim. Why is this true?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer By Am-Gm $a+\frac 1a+b+\frac 1b≥2+2=4$

Comment: @AndreasLenz We have that $x,y \in (0,\pi/2)$ though.

Comment: @AndreasLenz, we're in the first quadrant.

Comment: @Andreas No that is impossible.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Do you have Mathematica or Maple..?I'm really wondering, can the minimum be less than $6$?.

Comment: Sadly, I don't, and I probably wouldn't know how to use them well. Also, ignore my previous comment, I forgot the constraint $\sin(x+y) = 2/3$. Graphing that as well, we have [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h3ru5p0s8d) (for the original function set equal to $5.9$). Based on this and how the graph behaves for nearby values of $c$ (even for $c=5.9999$ the red and green lines don't cross), I think $6$ is the global minimum.

Comment: EeveeTrainer Thank you for your comment. But, WA says there is no global minimum..Maybe my input is wrong...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplifying gives: $$\frac{\sin x}{\cos y}+\frac {\cos x}{\sin y}+\frac{\sin y}{\cos x}+\frac{\cos y}{\sin x}=\frac{\sin^2 x+\cos^2y}{\sin x\cos y}+\frac {\cos^2 x+\sin^2y}{\sin y\cos x}=\frac{\sin(x+y)\sin(x-y)+1}{\sin x\cos y}+\frac {1-\sin(x+y)\sin(x-y)}{\sin y\cos x}=\frac {8}{3\sin2x\sin 2y}+\frac{2\sin (x-y)}{3}\left(\frac{1}{\sin x\cos y}-\frac{1}{\sin y\cos x}\right)=\frac {8}{3\sin2x\sin 2y}-\frac 83\frac{\sin^2(x-y)}{\sin2x\sin 2y}=\frac{8\cos^2(x-y)}{3\sin 2x\sin2y}=\frac{16\cos^2(x-y)}{3(\cos 2(x-y)-\cos 2(x+y))}=\frac{16}{3(2-10/9\sec^2(x-y))}$$

The denominator is maximum when $\sec^2(x-y)$ is minimum, which happens when $x=y$, in which case the quantity has value $6$. So the required global minimum should be $6$.

**Edit:** The edit shows that the given expression (let's call it $f(x,y)$ for brevity) can't take any value smaller than $6$. To see that, let's first note (Refer **Note**) that $\color{blue}{ 2-\frac {10}9\sec^2(x-y)\gt 0 \text{ for all } (x,y)\in (0,\frac \pi 2)\times (0,\frac \pi 2)}$.

Suppose on the contrary that there exist some $a$ and $b$ in $(0,\frac \pi 2)$ such that $f(a,b)<6$. It follows that $$\frac{16}{3(2-10/9\sec^2(x-y))}\lt 6\implies 8<18-10\sec^2(x-y)\implies \sec^2(x-y)\lt 1 $$ and this is a contradiction. So the assumption that $f$ takes any value less than $6$ is wrong. Hence global minimum value of $f$ under the given conditions is $6$.

**Note:** If $\sec^2(x-y)\ge \frac{18}{10}$ then $\cos^2(x-y)\le \frac {10}{18}\implies 0\lt \cos (x-y)\le \sqrt {\frac{10}{18}}$ (because $x-y \in (-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$ so $\cos $ is +ve) so let's consider two cases: 1) $0\le x-y)\lt \frac \pi 2 \text{ and } 2) -\frac \pi 2\lt x-y \lt 0$.

Case 1: it follows that $x-y\ge \arccos\sqrt {\frac{10}{18}}$ (noting that $\cos$ is decreasing on $[0,\pi/2))$. Given that $x+y=\arcsin \frac 23$, it follows that $y\le 0$ which is not possible.

Case 2: it follows that $x-y\le -\arccos\sqrt {\frac{10}{18}}$ (noting that $\cos$ is increasing on $(-\frac \pi 2, 0))$. Then proceeding as in case 1) results in a contradiction.

This establishes the blue colored part.

Comment: @I'mastudent: I have used inverse trigonometric functions in cases 1) and 2) and the fact that cos is decreasing on $[0,\frac \pi 2]$ and increasing on $(-\frac \pi 2, 0)$. Is something unclear to you?

Comment: I want to wrote directly $\frac{16}{3(2-10/9\sec^2(x-y))}≥\frac{16}{3(2-10/9)}=6.$ is it okay?

Comment: @I'mastudent: That's perfect, yes! That also avoids "Edit" and "Note" in the answer completely.

Comment: I would love for your answer to be a truly pedagogical one.  For example, how you did the steps and etc.  You suddenly wrote $\sin^2x+\cos^2y=1+\sin(x+y)\sin(x-y)$ and I just proved it.  But how did you come to this conclusion directly?  Have you experienced this formula before?  In other lines, you suddenly took the trigonometric expression out of the parentheses.  Honestly, I wanted to understand what was going on, but I couldn't.

Comment: @I'mastudent: At the time of writing the answer, I had the identity $\sin ^2 x-\sin^2y=\sin (x+y)\sin(x-y)$ in mind and tried to cast the given expression in a form wherein I can apply that identity. I skipped intermediary steps like $\sin^2x+\color{blue}{\cos^2y}=\sin^2x+\color{blue}{(1-\sin^2y)}$ etc. I felt that analysing $\frac{8\cos^2(x-y)}{3\sin 2x\sin2y}$ as it is, would be difficult due to $3$ variable terms present in it. (Contd.)

Comment: (Contd.) so I tried to further simplify it to an expression (i.e., $\frac{16}{3(2-10/9\sec^2(x-y))}$) wherein I have to handle only one variable term i.e. $\sec^2(x-y)$ hence resulting in  easier analysis of the given expression.

Comment: In my book there is no such an identity. $$\sin^2x-\sin^2y=\sin(x+y)\sin(x-y)$$. Is this a well known identity? E.g. like a $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$.

Comment: @I'mastudent: I'm not sure what you mean by "well known". Note that the identity is true and can be proven using double angle formulae of $\cos 2A$.  Another identity that you may like is: $\cos^2x-\sin^2y=\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y)$. :)

Comment: $\sin (x+y)\sin (x-y)=\sin^2x\cos^2y-\cos^2y\sin^2y$ What I mean, the result doesn't seem trivial

Comment: @I'mastudent: In my last comment, this is the proof I had in mind: $\sin^2x-\sin^2y=\frac12\{(1-\cos 2x) -(1-\cos 2y)\}=\frac 12 (\cos 2y-\cos 2x)=\frac 12 .2\sin\frac{2y+2x}2\sin \frac{2x-2y}2=\sin(x+y)\sin(x-y)$. I met this identity for the first time in or before year 2012 as a part of an exercise problem if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t:=x-y$ and $u:=x+y$. We have

$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos y}+\frac {\cos x}{\sin y}+\frac{\sin y}{\cos x}+\frac{\cos y}{\sin x}=2\cos(t)(\csc(2y)+\csc(2x))=\frac{4\sin(u)\cos^2(t)}{\cos^2(t)-\cos^2(u)}.$$
As $u$ is known to be constant, we have a univariate function in $t$. It has a stationary point at $t=0$, giving

$$\sin(x+y)=\sin(2x)=\frac23$$ and

$$2\tan(2x)+2\cot(2x)=6.$$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  Let $$f(x,y) = g + \frac{1}{g} + h + \frac{1}{h}$$ where $$g(x,y) = \frac{\sin x}{\cos y}, \quad h(x,y) = \frac{\cos x}{\sin y}.$$  Then since $0 \le x, y \le \pi/2$, we must have $0 \le \sin x, \cos x, \sin y, \cos y \ge 1$, hence $g, h \ge 0$.  Then AM-GM proves $g + 1/g \ge 2$, as well as $h + 1/h \ge 2$, thus $f \ge 4$, and this is without the added constraint $\sin (x+y) = \frac{2}{3}$.  None of the answer choices is greater than $4$, so all are incorrect.

But also be advised that Wolfram Alpha is also misleading, because we have established that it is impossible for $f$ to be negative.  Thus there must be a lower bound.

The actual minimum is $6$.  To see this, let $c_1 = \arcsin \frac{2}{3} \approx 0.729728$, and $c_2 = \pi - c_1 \approx 2.41186$.  These comprise the two possible values for $x + y$ in the square $[0,\pi/2]^2$.  Then the transformation $u = x+y$, $v = x-y$ gives
$$f = 8\frac{\sin u \cos^2 v}{\cos 2v - \cos 2u} = 4 \frac{\sin u \cos^2 v}{ \cos^2 v + \sin^2 u - 1}$$  Then since $\sin u = 2/3$,
$$f = \frac{24\cos^2 v}{-5 + 9 \cos^2 v} = \frac{8}{3} + \frac{\frac{40}{27}}{t - \frac{5}{9}}$$ where $t = \cos^2 v$.  Consider the range of $t$.  Since $x + y \in \{c_1, c_2\}$ and $0 \le x, y \le \pi/2$, it follows that $0 \le |x-y| \le c_1$, and in turn, $$\frac{5}{9} \le t \le 1.$$  As $f$ is obviously a decreasing function of $t$ on this interval, the minimum is attained when $t$ is as large as possible, namely $t = 1$, corresponding to $v = 0$, or $x = y \in \{c_1/2, c_2/2\}$, and $$f = \frac{8}{3} + \frac{40/27}{4/9} = 6.$$

---

Here is a plot of $f(x,y)$ and the two curves for which $\sin (x+y) = \frac{2}{3}$.  As you can see, they do have a global minimum, and as $f$ is never negative, neither are the curves.

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you very much.  But, Unfortunately I can not understand,  meaning of "global minimum doesn't exist, only local minimum exist.Does this mean, expression can be less than $6$?In WA graph I see colored spots when "expression<6. But, why?...

Comment: @I'mastudent No, the WA graph is wrong.  That's what I'm trying to show you.  Sometimes, WA will produce incorrect results, either because it doesn't interpret your input in the way you want, or because there is a bug.

Comment: Thank you again. I tried the same input for "expression<4", but I did not see any colored spots. So, I confused.

Comment: @I'mastudent Can you provide a link to the input you sent to WA?  That way, I might be able to better determine what is happening.

Comment: Thank you! 1) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimum+sinx%2Fcosy+%2Bcosy%2Fsinx%2Bcos+x%2Fsiny%2Bsiny%2Fcos+x+where+sin%28x%2By%29%3D2%2F3+and+0%3Cx%3Cpi%2F2+and+0%3Cy%3Cpi%2F2

Comment: 2)https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sinx%2Fcosy+%2Bcosy%2Fsinx%2Bcos+x%2Fsiny%2Bsiny%2Fcos+x%3C6+and+sin%28x%2By%29%3D2%2F3+and+0%3Cx%3Cpi%2F2+and+0%3Cy%3Cpi%2F2

Comment: 3) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sinx%2Fcosy+%2Bcosy%2Fsinx%2Bcos+x%2Fsiny%2Bsiny%2Fcos+x%3C4+and+sin%28x%2By%29%3D2%2F3+and+0%3Cx%3Cpi%2F2+and+0%3Cy%3Cpi%2F2

Comment: I think WA is right. The given expression can take negative values also. For example: in my answer what if $\sec (x-y)=100$.

Comment: @Koro Your example is impossible.  If $\sec(x-y) = 100$, then you cannot also have $\sin (x+y) = 2/3$ in the square $[0,\pi/2]^2$.

Comment: @I'mastudent Your second and third inputs show that there are no points satisfying those simultaneous conditions.  The first input gives the solution, but the issue with the global minimum not being found may be a limitation of WA.  I was not able to find in the documentation of `GlobalMinima` any further insights.

Comment: But, What is the meaning of colored spots?

Comment: @Koro why $\sec (x-y)=1$ ?

Comment: heropup: Yes, the example is impossible. Thanks :)

Comment: @Koro Was your solution incorrect?

Comment: @I'mastudent: no. I'm editing it to include a proof that the given expression can't take any value smaller than $6$.

Comment: @Koro why $\sec (x-y)=1$?

Comment: @I'mastudent: $\sec t$ on [0, $\frac \pi 2$) is minimum when $t=0$. I'll share my updated answer shortly.

Comment: @Koro We need the minimum $\frac 1{\cos ^2(x-y)}$, when $0<x,y<\frac {\pi}{2}$. . This doesn't imply directly $x=y$. Please, dont use $\sec$ notation

Comment: @heropup can you provide a new part answer using derivatives? is it possible?

Comment: @I'mastudent: Note that $x-y\in (-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$ so the cos(x-y) is always non-zero and attains maximum only when $x-y=0$. Please refer my revised answer wherein I have added lot more details.